# Error 500: Filter [Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter]: could not be loaded

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to deploy a Spring application on WAS 6.0 (JDK 1.4.2). Day back I was getting tons of (Unsupported major.minor version 49.0) errors. I replaced most of the jar files and now I am left with only one error on:

org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter (Unsupported major.minor version 49.0)

what jar file do I need to replace for this? Also when I am running my URL in the browser I am getting the error:

Error 500: Filter [Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter]: could not be loaded

Can you please guide me ,where exactly I am doing wrong. Attached is my Web.xml.

Your help is highly appreciated.

```
enter code here
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    analytics
    Roo generated analytics application

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>analytics.root</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
```

log4jConfigLocation
classpath:log4j.properties


org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener


        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>analytics</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Serves static resource content from .jar files such as spring-js.jar -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>analytics</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Map all /resources requests to the Resource Servlet for handling -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>analytics</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
        /*

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/uncaughtException.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Unsupported major.minor version" errors are caused by your using JAR files compiled for a higher version of java than you're running.

I think class file version 49.0 is Java 5, and you're running 1.4. That means you must be using a library that's Java 5 only, and the only version of Spring thats java 5 only is Spring 3.0. If that's the case, then downgrade your Spring to 2.5.6.